# The reason of the output in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

Here is the code

```
function fn(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var tc=setTimeout(function(i){
        console.log(i)
        clearTimeout(tc)
      },10,i);
  }
}
fn()
//0, 1, 2 - output
```

I can't understand why the output is not '0, 1, 2, 3',only output three times.

Even more stranger is below

When I change the loop times, now, I call loop times as T.

```
T: 1 ---> 0   

T: 2 ---> 0   

T: 3 ---> 0, 1
```

above, the right is the output.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Printing value of i every 10 ms? If that the case, the logic of your code is wrong.

Comment: @Noobit I just wonder the output is 0, 1, 2. I can't figure out the reson.

Comment: Cause clearTimeout(tc) cleared the last one. Actually, it clear whatever failed to execute fast enough since var tc does not mean create new instance in a for loop. It only create one instance tc, and passes the reference to the next loop.

Comment: so you mean the '2'  is be output at the loop of the third? and if the '3' need be output, it should at the loop of the fourth?

Comment: No, it just clear the last one. You can stop it from doing that by passing the tc into the setTimeout scope.

function fn(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var tc=setTimeout(function(i,tc){
            console.log(i);
            clearTimeout(tc);
        },10,i,tc);
    }
}
fn();

Comment: function(i) => function(i,tc) and pass variable tc.

Comment: FYI. When i pasted your code into my IDE, it tells me that tc is out of scope. I think most decent IDE will tell you the error right away. What are you using to code? Please don't tell me it's a notepad T-T

Comment: @radical see my answer below.. `closure` is the prblm

Comment: @Noobit Actually, I found these code at other website. I use sublime3.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Print i out at interval T.

```
function fn(){
    var T = 1000;
    var func = function(i,len) {
        if ( i < len ) {
            console.log(i);
            setTimeout(func,T,i+1,len); // Calling itself.
        }
    };
    setTimeout(func,T,0,4);
}
fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

At last got it...The problem is with `closure`..You just need to pass the variable `tc` to `setTimeout` function.

```js
function fn(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var tc=setTimeout(function(i,tc){
        console.log(i)
        clearTimeout(tc);
      },10,i,tc);
  }
}
fn()
```

Comment: this my first answer, but logically, it's wrong from what I understood of what he wanted to do. He wanted to print out at T interval. Doing it like this will print them all out at T, that is i to len, instead of i, i+n, i+n at Tn. I deleted this before, just re-enable it now to show him the error. Sorry didn't see you update your answer. I deleted mine again.

Comment: @Mendax Look at my solution. Overwritng the tc value is the problem.

Comment: @PankajShukla of course. that is the reason. :) that is what I said too.. The variable gets overriden because same instance is used. That is why we have passed that varible. so that the variable will have that function scope.

Comment: @Mendax Passing the variable is not really required. As long as clearTimeout is done on the same variable "value" that was obtained from setTimeout, we are good.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are overwriting the value of tc in the for loop.
By overwriting, you lose handle to corresponding return value from each call to `setTimeout()`.

You need to clear individual tc as you go in the for loop.
So, something like this would work.
Note that I have hard-coded, tc array but you can make it generic, so this example is just for a reference as to how you could get 0,1,2,3.

```js
var tc = [0,0,0,0];
    function fn(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            tc[i]=setTimeout(function(i){
                console.log(i);
                clearTimeout(tc[i]);
            },10,i);
        }
    }
    fn();
```

Comment: I know i overwrite the value of tc.  But I don't know why loop four times, but the function tc only execute three times. As @Noobit said, the reason is about  clearTimeout(tc) cleared the last one. So why T = 0 || T = 1 , all only output '0'

Comment: @radical That is the explanation why the code behaves undesirably. Overwriting should be avoided.

Comment: yes. I just read these code at other website and confused the result of run.

Comment: @radical Yes, by clearing the right timeout(not the overwritten) solves the problem.